# Can't display the chosen items per page using Pagination (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, api, pagination

I am using Angular's Pagination (Angular Material) to display items on a table that I get from an external API.

Right now I can only see the initial (default) number of items (count) that are in each page.

**My problem is that I can't change the displayed items per page when I choose another number, they stay the same.**

What am I doing wrong, am I missing something?

characters.component.html

```
<div class="main-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input>
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="CharacterName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Character Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{element.name}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="TvShows">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tv Shows </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tvShows}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="VideoGames">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Video Games </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.videoGames}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Allies">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Allies </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.allies}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Enemies">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Enemies </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.enemies}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator
    [pageSize]="paginatorConfig?.items_count"
    [pageSizeOptions]="paginatorConfig?.pageSizeOptions"
    [length]="paginatorConfig?.total_items"
      showFirstLastButtons (page)="paginatorChanges($event)"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

characters.component.ts

```
import { HttpService } from './../http.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-characters',
  templateUrl: './characters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./characters.component.scss']
})
export class CharactersComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'CharacterName',
    'TvShows',
    'VideoGames',
    'Allies',
    'Enemies',
  ];
  dataSource;
  paginatorConfig: {
    items_count: number,
    total_items: number,
    pageSizeOptions: number[];
  }

  // pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCharList();
  }

  getCharList(pageIndex?: number, pageSizeOptions?: number[]) {
    this.http.getCharacters(pageIndex, pageSizeOptions)
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resp.data);
        this.paginatorConfig = {
          items_count: resp.count,
          total_items: resp.count * resp.totalPages,
          pageSizeOptions: [resp.count * 10, 20]
        };
      });
  }

  //Search and find desired character
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  paginatorChanges(event) {
    this.getCharList(event.pageIndex + 1);
  }
}
```

http.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCharacters(pageIndex: number = 1, pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500]) {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.disneyapi.dev/characters/?page=${pageIndex}&per_page=${pageSizeOptions}`);
  }
}
```